# How to extract information about exact company through Yahoo! local

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-api

I have a company: http://local.yahoo.com/info-19134823-integrity-roofing-painting-houston

And I want to get reviews from it. I tried to use LocalSearch API... No results. Does any company ID existed? If it is, I can ask my client to provide it... Maybe I should use not localSearch, maybe other API. Help me please.

P.S. I saw Local API(http://developer.yahoo.com/search/local/V3/localSearch.html)

**Update**: I've found that I should use `listing_id` param. Is it correct? Where can I find it if I have a dealer link?

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out how to do it:
`http://local.yahooapis.com/LocalSearchService/V3/localSearch?appid=YahooDemo&listing_id=19134823&query=*&output=json`

All needed was `query=*`